# Optimizing perimeter on Cartesian Plane

Tags: geometry

Construct 3 points on the plane with the form $(0,0),(x,0) ,(0,y)$
and a line. Let $(a,b)$ be on the line, what is the value of $a,b$ if we want to minimize the perimeter of the quadrilateral made by connecting the 4 points?

I don't know how to start this, but I am thinking about special cases like 2 sides are equal but I tried them and it does not seem like the case

Comment: The first paragraph is completely unclear.

Comment: We're missing information about the line. Which line are you talking about?

Comment: uhm,(0,0), (x,0) and (0,y) are points , x and y are fixed. the line is any line on the plane,(im trying to look at a general case)

Comment: @SuperMage1 I don't see how lines play a role in this, then. Why not just ask what point $(a,b)$ satisfies your condition?

Comment: It seems there is no minimum perimeter. Let the points be $O,A,B$ and $C$ in the order in which they appear in the OP. Then it suffices to minimize the distance $AC+CB$. This is minimal when $A,C$ and $B$ are collinear. In that case we do not have a quadrilateral.

Comment: This is known as Heron' problem: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/HeronsProblem.shtml